# Attributed text disappears in UITextView- Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, ibaction, nsmutableattributedstring

I have an array which has index 0 already filled, and this array stores NSStrings. I also have a "parallel" array which has index 0 already filled, and it stores NSNumbers.

In implementation:

```
@implementation ViewController

NSMutableArray *intonationStrings;
NSMutableArray *intonationSizes;
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

intonationStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"placeholderxyz", nil];

NSNumber *placeholderXYZ = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
intonationStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:placeholderXYZ, nil];

_resizeLyrics.minimumValue = 9;
_resizeLyrics.maximumValue = 40;
```

There is a slider with a minimum value of 9 and maximum of 40 which represents font size. There is a text field, and it's current text is used to create an NSRange within a text view to begin attributing the text. This action takes place inside of a button action:

```
-(IBAction)applyResizeAct:(id)sender{

 NSString *lyricString = _lyricPad.text;
 NSString *searchString = _searchLyrics.text;

 NSMutableAttributedString *lyricStringMut = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: lyricString];

 float sliderValue = _resizeLyrics.value;

 [intonationStrings addObject:searchString];
 [intonationSizes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sliderValue]];

 for (int i=1; i<[intonationStrings count]; i++){

     NSRange searchStringRange = [lyricString rangeOfString:intonationStrings[i]];
     NSInteger searchStringNewSize = [intonationSizes[i] integerValue];
     int searchStringNewSizeInteger = (int) searchStringNewSize;

      [lyricStringMut addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:searchStringNewSizeInteger] 
range:searchStringRange];
 }
self.lyricPad.attributedText = lyricStringMut;
}
```

The issue is I can't seem to figure out why typing "Pasta" in the text field, setting the slider to about 25 and tapping the button simply makes the word "Pasta" in the text view holding "Pasta is good." just disappear. My attribute should be applied: Font type Menlo at size 25 for "Pasta" and other sizes applied to strings in the parallel mutable array. Anything helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you do `self.lyricPad.attributedText = lyricStringMut;` inside a loop? Just set it once after the loop.

Comment: I tried that. I only moved it inside because it didn't work :/

Comment: Okay so NSNumber and float are the only data types returned correctly, when tested. I think there's a glitch with NSLog because it isn't working, so I set a random UITextField's text as the number to test. Float just makes the word disappear when tested in the UITextView with attributing. NSNumber is an incompatible type for performing that function. Running out of ideas. Also retrieving the stored NSNumber from the array shows to be null... so that's the main problem.